# Is there a D-module theory in characteristic p>0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

everyone.

In characteristic 0 we have a good theory of D-modules. In particular, we have a formalism of Grothendieck's six operators in the derived category of holonomic D-modules and Riemann-Hilbert correspondence.

In characteristic p>0, to my best knowledge, the proper notion that can replace 'D-module' is the stratified sheave (a sheave over the ring of Grothendieck differential operators). However I can't find much references on this topic.

So my question is: Is there a good theory of stratified sheave (parallel to the theory of D-modules)? In particular, a formalism of Grothendieck's six operators and Riemann-Hilbert correspondence.

Comment: There are "arithmetic D-modules" of Berthelot, maybe that's close to what you're looking for?

Comment: About filtration holonomic modules, in connection with $\cal{D}$-modules in positive characteristics: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hha/1139852458.